# Simulate the % in a \newcommand

Tags: macros, spacing

I want to automate quotation marks (not quotes) using a macro. Consider the following code:

```
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{``#1''}
```

This one works fine:

```
\mytext{This is a very long quote. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
```

But I want to make my source more readable by placing the text in a new line. The following code produces a space between the opening quotes and the first letter:

```
\mytext{
  This is a very long quote. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
```

Yes, this one will work:

```
\mytext
  {This is a very long quote. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
```

But I would prefer that `\mytext` would expand to something like this:

```
\mytext{%
  This is a very long quote. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
```

How do I create a `%` within a `\newcommand`?

Comment: Comments are never tokenized. There's no way to get them inside macros.

Comment: If you want to add quotes with a command, you can use `\enquote` from the `csquotes` package, which also handles quotes inside quotes and quotes in other languages. It doesn't remove the space though (neither at the beginning nor at the end), so this isn't really an answer...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{``\ignorespaces #1''}
```

Comment: Very nice. I was thinking about `\ignorespaces`, but couldn't think where to put it to work. I came up with this elaborate solution involving `\afterassignment` and tail-recursive macros eating spaces. I'm glad I didn't embarrass myself by posting it!

Comment: If you stick `\unskip` after `#1`, then you can remove trailing spaces too (more or less).