# Remove space at the end of a macro

Tags: macros, spacing

For a particular work, I need old style footnotes, that are typeset before the word they refer to.

So I call `\footnote` before the word and it works fine, but it adds a space after the footnote mark. How can I get read of this space (in essence, the opposite of `\xspace`)?

Comment: Just use `\ignorespaces`.

See also [Simulate the % in a \newcommand](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/simulate-the-in-a-newcommand)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  A test \footnote{a test foot}sentence.
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample foot]

I did not see the space you talked about in the question. Did you left a space or newline between the `}` and the letters following it?

Comment: My bad, I was introducing a space in the wrapper for my notes.

Comment: Alternativ you may finish your \footnote{...} with a % and continue on the thext line. (I edited the answer, please wait for a peer review).

Answer (score 7):

Yan Zhou has probably given the irght answer, but I'd add that in similar cases, `\ignorespaces` or `\unskip` can be useful. Assume for instance that a macro you are using starts and ends with spurious spaces. Then you may be able to fix it without redefining it:

```
\newcommand{\badmacro}{ Hello }
\newcommand{\fixedmacro}{\ignorespaces\badmacro\unskip}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x\badmacro x\fixedmacro x
\end{document}
```